# Aligning Issues with flash file in CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css, object, alignment

I am having some problems with aligning an object in my HTML page. I've searched high and low and there were many solutions such as setting both the right and left margin to auto and using `margin:0 auto;` in CSS. Even typing in `align="center"` in the html code does not work.

My codes are here: http://jsfiddle.net/qzfwt7j8/1/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show us a jsFiddle. Based on only the code you've given us, Suresh's answer should have worked for you. So obviously we're missing something you're not providing. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add one parent div and apply `margin:0px auto` and also width 550

```
<div style="margin:0px auto; width:550px;">
       <object class="ACGame" width="550" height="400" data="AppleCatcher.swf"></object>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. But i tried it and it made no difference. Would it be worth mentioning that all of my content is in one giant table? I did it cause so that I would be able to center align everything on the page.

Comment: Using tables for a whole site is old fashioned you should use divs it's much easier :) And has a lot of benefits for example SEO (Search engine optimalization) And a lot easier to use with CSS. You will notice that when you work with tables it just doesn't always do what you ask of it.

Comment: The edit worked for me! Thanks a lot, but not sure why though.
@SinanSamet Haha I'm very new to this. In fact I picked it up today and I'm still trying to find my way around, but i'll try to experiment with it! :)

Comment: That's because you need to assign a width if you use margin: 0 auto; to align to center because otherwise it would center the 100% width which is already centered.